# File upload error in easy-ftp with electron & node.js app

Tags: javascript, node.js, ftp, electron

I am trying to upload csv files in remote ftp using [easy-ftp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/easy-ftp) package but sometimes uploads & sometimes showing error like below image

[image]

here is my code

```
let ftp = new EasyFtp();
try{
    const config = {
        host: 'ftp.saba.com',
        port: 21,
        username: 'username',
        password: 'password',
        type : 'ftp'
    };
    ftp.connect(config);
    ftp.upload(csvName, "/csvs/", function (err) {
        try {
            fs.unlink(csvName, (err) => {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                    return;
                }
            });
        } catch(error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    });
} catch(error) {
    console.log(error);
}
```

I can't find any helpful resources to overcome this issue, what can I do now?

Thanks

Comment: csvName is undefined , please console/debug this value

Comment: @MuhammadAli here is the value `c:\Users\LENOVO\Downloads\gst\gst/csvs/data_20190423_28ab5ac9-b72f-4138-b06c-70f2d53874fd.csv`

Comment: just set the path of your file inside your project ,, window directory slash are different with linux , like 'csvs/data_20190423_28ab5ac9-b72f-4138-b06c-70f2d53874fd.csv'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an asynchronous problem. You need to upload file after the connect is successful.

The code should be:

```
ftp.on('open', function(){
  ftp.upload(csvName, "/csvs/", function (err) {
    // process upload result
  });
});

ftp.connect(config);
```

In your code, the `upload` request is sent immediately after the `connect` operation. If lucky, when easy-ftp try to deliver the `upload` operation, the previous `connect` is already finished and successful, then `upload` would be successful too.

If unlucky, when easy-ftp try to deliver the `upload` operation, the previous `connect` is still not finished yet. Then the `upload` will fail and show "Cannot read property..." error (looks like easy-ftp should display some better error message).

To solve the problem, you need to listen the ["open" event](https://www.npmjs.com/package/easy-ftp) in easy-ftp, and only upload files when that event has been emitted:

> open(< FTPClient >client) - Emitted when connection and authentication were sucessful.

Comment: I have fixed using your concept but not code exactly. Thanks

Comment: You're welcome @jesica, as long as `upload` is invoked after `open` event, the code is good.